# Passing array of sheet controls to modify their properties

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to pass an array of (sheet) controls to another sub to modify their properties:

E.g.

```
Dim collChk(0 To 2) As ? ' Tried Variant, OLEObject, Control...
collChk(0) = chk0 
collChk(1) = chk1
collChk(2) = chk2
```

Sub:

```
Sub SetFalse(ByRef controls As ?)
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(controls) To UBound(controls)
    controls(i) = False
Next i
End Sub
```

But I keep getting: ByRef Argument Type mismatch or other errors

It could also be a Collection, that doesn't matter, but I have not been able to set that up too. I'm a bit lost what works how. Originally, the idea was to pass it as ParamArray, but errors popped out too.

(What would be great is simply to have a function that would work both with Sheet and UserForm controls but I want them specify manually and without duplication.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CheckBoxes:

```
Dim collChk(0 To 2) As MSForms.CheckBox
Set collChk(0) = Chk0
Set collChk(1) = Chk1
Set collChk(2) = Chk2
```

Note you need to use `Set` as they are objects. Then:

```
Sub SetFalse(ByRef controls() As MSForms.CheckBox)
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(controls) To UBound(controls)
    controls(i) = False
Next i
End Sub
```